# com.google.firebase.database.Query cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm implementing a simple search where it will filter based on if the text is the same as the record in the database but I'm having this error could someone help me?

Using equalsTo

I can't open the fragment it just breaks when trying to open the fragment, what am I doing wrong?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

---

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.Query cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
```

---

```
public class FindFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView FindFriendsRecyclerList;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    private MaterialSearchView searchView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friends);


        UsersRef = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("name").equalTo(String.valueOf(searchView));

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.materialSearchPrincipal);
        FindFriendsRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_recycler_list);
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        //Configurar botao de pesquisa
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuPesquisa);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                .setQuery(UsersRef, Contacts.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                    {
                        holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                        holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);


                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view)
                            {
                                String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                                startActivity(profileIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();
    }



    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        public FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `DatabaseReference`:

```
private Query UsersRef;
```

Comment: Works. One problem no show in recyclerview on put name of user :(. how to solve?

Comment: Is this considered good design???, IMO the DatabaseReference class should be a wrapper of a Query OR, the Query class should be an abstract generic class, but each time an additional query action is required by the DatabaseReference, it creates a new Query and loses the hierarchy.
My only guess why they didn't bother, is because the DBRef class was created as the merging point of Read (Query) and Write. But this is not really an excuse imo. 

Am I missing something?.